How to save and retrieve a value using Preferences Datastore in Jetpack Compose?
I'm trying to save a boolean value that determines if dark mode is active. If the boolean is true then the background color of the app will be dark gray, if false it will be white.
I want to save the boolean to preferences datastore so that the background color will be the same as the user's choosing upon relaunching the app. However it's not working.
Here is the MainActivity file. When launched it displays button. The button is supposed to change the value of the boolean variable isBackgroundColorDark and save the value to a preferences datastore key called backgroundColorKey.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            // Instance Of Background Color Datastore
            val backgroundColorDatastore = BackgroundColorDatastore(this)

            // Variable That Holds Background Color Preference
            val backgroundColorPreference = backgroundColorDatastore.loadBackgroundColorPreference(
                key = backgroundColorDatastore.backgroundColorKey).collectAsState(initial = false)

            // Boolean Variable That Determines Background Color
            var isBackgroundColorDark by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

            // Launched Effect That Loads Background Color Preference
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = isBackgroundColorDark) {
                backgroundColorPreference.value
            }

            // Page Layout
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = if (isBackgroundColorDark) Color.DarkGray else Color.White)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                // Button That Changes Background Color
                Button(onClick = { CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    isBackgroundColorDark = !isBackgroundColorDark
                    backgroundColorDatastore.saveBackgroundColorPreference(
                        key = backgroundColorDatastore.backgroundColorKey,
                        data = isBackgroundColorDark)
                }}
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Change Background Color")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the datastore that holds the backgroundColorKey and the save and load functions:
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("Background Color Datastore")

class BackgroundColorDatastore(private val context: Context) {
    // Background Color Key
    val backgroundColorKey = booleanPreferencesKey("Background Color Key")

    // Function That Loads Background Color Preference
    fun loadBackgroundColorPreference(key: Preferences.Key<Boolean>): Flow<Boolean> =      
        context.dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        preferences[key] ?: false
    }
    // Function That Saves Background Color Preference
    suspend fun saveBackgroundColorPreference(key: Preferences.Key<Boolean>, data: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[key] = data
        }
    }
}

Whenever I relaunch the app the settings are reset and the background color is white.

Datastore operations should not be in the UI layer. It is the same for View and Compose.

I recommend taking Android's Datastore Codelab to help you understand working with datastore.

You load the data store value, but you never do anything with it.
Remove the current isBackgroundColorDark state and directly save the data store value in isBackgroundColorDark instead:
// Variable That Holds Background Color Preference
val isBackgroundColorDark by backgroundColorDatastore.loadBackgroundColorPreference(
    key = backgroundColorDatastore.backgroundColorKey).collectAsState(initial = false)

The LaunchedEffect didn't do anthing in the first place so that can be removed as well.
Now, when you click the button, you just need to save the new value:
backgroundColorDatastore.saveBackgroundColorPreference(
    key = backgroundColorDatastore.backgroundColorKey,
    data = !isBackgroundColorDark,
)

And that's it: You now only have a single state in your compose code to indicate light or dark. That is directly retrieved from the datastore, and whenever that changes the state changes as well.
Also note that you should remember BackgroundColorDatastore so it won't be recreated on every recomposition. Also you should not use CoroutineScope in your composables, use rememberCoroutineScope outside the callback to retrieve a scope and access it inside the callback.
The above wouldn't even be necessary if you'd move the data store code into a view model and the data layer respectively.
